# PATCH method blocked by a firewall?

Tags: rest, firewall

Hi anyone ever had a situation that a `PATCH` method over `XHR` (AJAX requests) was blocked by a firewall ?

Basically we had a situation where a client was complaining that he couldn't update stuff on our app. We checked it everywhere in the world it was working (we connected via `VPN` several places)

Then they provided us a remote desktop (latest Windows, latest chrome) so we tried it for our-self from their network, and they were right. All PATCH methods via `AJAX` calls ended up with 405 but all `PUT POST DELETE GET` methods were fine. We tried to track these PATCH requests in application and `Nginx` logs but it seems they never hit our server. So conclusion is that their firewall newer let the request leave the building.

normal:

```
| Laptop PATCH  ->  Clients Firewal   ->   Load Balancer   ->  Nginx proxy  -> Rails app (200 response) |
```

this firewall case:

```
| Laptop PATCH ->  Clients Firewal  (405 response)   |
```

Due to lack of time to investigate this we just changed some of these problematic endpoints from PATCH to PUT, and everything was working !

my only explanation in that because PATCH is part of another (later introduced) RFC their firewall must be super old and not registering PATCH as a valid method. Their sys-admin have no idea why this could be. But one clue is that the application is EdTech and clients are Schools => they not necessarily may have the latest technology on their networking stack. Also nanny-software may be preset.

cross-reference to Reddit discussion on same question: https://www.reddit.com/r/rest/comments/5gkvba/patch_blocked_by_firewall/

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding the firewall, name, version?

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot. The support and information knowledge from the client we received was pretty much in a sense: "we don't know". Only thing we were able to do is to try the calls from remote desktop. Unfortunately I no longer have the header information but one thing I remember is that when the 405 occurred the header had "Squid" header. So could it be that Squid cached PATCH?  (as PATCH is cachable )

Comment: OK, sounds like they helped as much as they could. I don't know much about Squid but it does indicate the setup it quite old.

Comment: In the old days we would simply switch to https. Most firewalls leave https traffic alone.

Comment: this was happening under HTTPs unfortunately (entire app is under https) , but good idea doh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Still don't quite know why this was happening but I'm pretty sure that due to PATCH method being younger than the firewall setup.

Basically proper workaround would be to replace PATCH with POST as both are non-idempotent.

HTTP standard best practice tells that you should not replace it with PUT, although some web-frameworks (like Ruby on Rails) make it too darn easy. The thing is that you may end up with other problems due to intermediary devices repeating PUT as it's idempotent.

I've summarized entire story in article http://www.eq8.eu/blogs/37-post-create-and-put-updatepost